# Use of regex in replace() to join split words in a text

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, newline

I have this sample sentences in a plain text file (utf-8):

```
today is an interest-
ing day
```

the "-" on the first line is followed by only `\n`  (I have already stripped all `\r` from the file, to deal uniformy with different sources)
I would like to wrap the 2 lines in 1 line, because of the "-", meaning that the preceding word has been truncated and is continuing in the next line.
To join this kind of lines, what I have tried is something along the lines:

```
text.replace(/[\n-]/g, "")
```

but does not seem to be working. What is the right way to achieve this ?

I would like to be able to deal with both these possible endings (or similar situations you might anticipate):

```
interest-\n
interest- \n    (possible blanks inserted before \n)
```

Comment: Does the sample data contain a typo? Addressing duplicated characters `interest-\nsting` is vastly different than simply hyphens `interest-\ning`

Comment: @coll  You are right. I left some extra char in. Let me fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
text.replace(/\b-\s*\n\b/g, "")
text.replace(/\b-[^\S\r\n]*\n\b/g, "")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/T2IEUy/1). *Details*:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `-` - a hyphen
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces / `[^\S\r\n]*` - zero or more horizontal whitespaces (supporting CRLF, CR and LF endings)
- `\n` - a newline char
- `\b` - a word boundary.

See the JavaScript demo:

```js
console.log( "today is an interest- \ning day".replace(/\b-\s*\n\b/g, "") );
console.log( "today is an interest-\ning day".replace(/\b-\s*\n\b/g, "") );
```

A Unicode-aware pattern that checks for just letters on both ends can look like `text.replace(/(?<=\p{L}\p{M}*)-[^\S\r\n]*\n(?=\p{L})/gu, "")`, where `(?<=\p{L}\p{M}*)` checks for a letter + optional diacritics before `-` and `(?=\p{L})` checks for a letter after a newline. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/T2IEUy/2).

Comment: Thanks a lot Wiktor! I was not aware of this tool about regex. I am going to play with it, to see if I can finally learn this esoteric stuff :-)

Answer (score 0):

There are three things wrong in your regex for this use:

1. You have the new line before the -
2. The [] means a list of characters to match at least one of them
3. You need to add \s to match whitespace

So try this:

```
text.replace(/-\s*\n/g, "")
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and answer. It's very useful as I am just learning this stuff. Cheers!